# Cliente Rest em Java recebendo um LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, rest

Estou fazendo um cliente teste em java.

Minha classe livro é assim:

```
public class Livro {

    private Long id;
    private String nome;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate publicacao;

    private String editora;
    private String resumo;
    private List<Comentario> comentarios;
    private Autor autor;

   // get and sets
}
```

Recebo o seginte json.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Livro de teste 2",
    "publicacao": "20/05/2014",
    "editora": "teste",
    "resumo": "teste de resumo"
  }
]
```

Se utilizo o campo `publicacao` como `Date` funciona perfeitamente.
Mas gostaria de utilizar como `Localdate` como esta definido na Clase
Contudo da o seguinte erro.

> Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/05/2014'
>   could not be parsed at index 0    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>     at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)    at
>   java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:385)     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:67)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:32)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:490)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:341)
>     ... 14 more

Ou seja como faço o parse de um campo json `"publicacao": "20/05/2014"`,
para um campo `Localdate` ?

Para fazer o client estou utilizando as seguintes dependencias no maven.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude a versão da dependência `jackson-datatype-jsr310` para a mesma versão da dependência `jackson-databind`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

E registre o módulo `JavaTimeModule` ao invés do módulo `JSR310Module`. Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    Livro livro = mapper.readValue("{\"id\": 1,"
                                + "\"nome\": \"Livro de teste 2\", "
                                + "\"publicacao\": \"20/05/2014\","
                                + "\"editora\": \"teste\","
                                + "\"resumo\": "
                                + "\"teste de resumo\"}", Livro.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Opa!

Atualmente na minha aplicação estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@Column(name = "data_vencimento")
private LocalDate dataVencimento;
```

Espero ter ajudado!